# Why don't we use pointers with arrays instead of a full blown linked list?

Tags: arrays, linked-list

[image: This is a picture to demonstrate what I am trying to explain.]So I was recently implementing a linked list and asked this question to myself. In a linked list a lot of space is wasted as for each value we have to supplement a pointer to the next node. So why don't we just use an array and use its last element as a pointer to another array. If we need to insert just an element then we will insert an array of length 2. Else we can save space when more elements need to be inserted as every element will be grouped in an array and the last element will be a pointer to the next array or it can be NULL.

Comment: I think it would use more memory using an array. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but if your datas take 10 bytes, you'll need to `malloc(2 * 10);`, for a single node with the next being `null`. 20 bytes versus `malloc(10 + sizeof *something));` that results in 14 or 18 bytes (depending of 32 or 64 bits)

Comment: i think you did not get me. My point is when i am using more than one node then the memory usage will be less

Comment: How would you handle inserting an element in the middle of a sub-array?

Comment: That is a limitation but if i know i may need to insert an element in between some elements then i will use only arrays of length 2

Comment: and how would you indicate which part of a sub-array is data and which part is a link? Assume a size parameter is used, that's 4 elements for a 2 element array, size, element, element, link.

Comment: the last element will be a link and others will be data